# Is checking existence of a method inside a class a violation of SOLID principles?

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles, design-principles

I have a class called Bird that accepts array of birds in the constructor. I am trying to implement a function inside it that will check if any of the birds is currently flying, keeping in mind that all code should comply with SOLID principles.

I have the following two classes (Parrot and Ostrich)

```
class Parrot extends FlyingBirds{}   
class Ostrich extends BirdDetail{}
```

BirdDetail Class

```
abstract class BirdDetail {

  protected $didNotSleepLastNight;

  public function __construct(bool $didNotSleepLastNight)
  {
    $this->didNotSleepLastNight= $didNotSleepLastNight;
  }

  public function didNotSleepLastNight(): bool
  {
    return $this->didNotSleepLastNight;
  }

}
```

FlyingBirds (Not all birds can fly, like ostrich)

```
abstract class FlyingBirds extends BirdDetail{

 protected $isFlyingNow;

 public function __construct(bool $didNotSleepLastNight, bool $isFlyingNow)
 {
    parent::__construct($didNotSleepLastNight);
    $this->isFlyingNow = $isFlyingNow;
 }

 public function isFlyingNow(): bool
 {
    return $this->isFlyingNow;
 }
}
```

Then I have a class called Bird

```
class Bird
{
  private $details;

 public function __construct(array $details)
 {
    $this->details = $details;
 }

 public function didNotSleepLastNight(): bool
 {
    foreach ($this->details as $detail) {

        if ($detail->didNotSleepLastNight()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
 }

 public function isFlyingNow(): bool
 {
    foreach ($this->details as $detail) {

        if ($detail->isFlyingNow()) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now I am passing instances of Parrot and Ostrich to Bird Constructor

```
$bird = new Bird([new Parrot(true, false), new Ostrich(false)]);     

if($bird->isFlyingNow())
{
 echo "Yes";
}
else
{
 echo "No";
}
```

The problem is The above code is giving me the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Ostrich::isFlyingNow()
```

That is because Ostrich/BirdDetail class does not have a method called isFlyingNow.

The problem can be fixed by the replacing the isFlyingNow method in Birds class with the following code:

```
public function isFlyingNow(): bool
{

    foreach ($this->details as $detail) {

        if (method_exists($detail, 'isFlyingNow') && $detail->isFlyingNow())             
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Could you please tell me if the above fix is some sort of violation of SOLID principles? Or can the problem be solved in a better way?

Comment: An alternative to `method_exists` is using `instanceof FlyingBirds`.

Comment: It seems that `detail` accepts `BirdDetail[]` and as such it does not have `isFlyingNow()` in its interface. It violates the L of SOLID.

Comment: @thyagostall Thanks for you reply. Could you please tell me how to fix the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really breaking SOLID, but simply not very well designed.

For a neater approach, use interfaces.

Since not all birds can fly, having a public facing method `isFlying()` for all birds seems rather wasteful.

Maybe you could do something like this:

Your base `Bird` class, where you'd define the common properties and methods for all birds.

```php
class Bird {
}
```

Then, different interfaces to describe different possible behaviours of Bird subclasses. Some birds fly, some swim, some talk, some sing, some dive, some can run, etc, etc.

For the flyers:

```php
interface FlyingBird {

    function isFlying():bool;

    function takeOff();

    function land();

    function fly($bearing, $distance);

}
```

For the talkers:

```php
interface TalkingBird {

    function say($something);
}
```

The singers:

```php
interface SingingBird {
    function sing(array $notes);
}
```

The swimmers (you may need to differentiate those that swim on the surface of the water and those that can dive underneath the surface).

```
interface SwimmingBird {
   function isSwimming(): bool;
   // etc
}
```

For the runners:

```
interface RunningBird {
   function isRunning(): bool;
   // etc
}
```

Then you could have classes like `Parrot` (flies and talks, but doesn't do singing, running, or swimming)

```php
class Parrot extends Bird implements TalkingBird, FlyingBird {
    // todo: actual implementation
}
```

Or `Ostrich` (can run, but doesn't swim, sing, talk or fly):

```
class Ostrich extend Birds implements RunningBird { /* implementation */}
```

Or even `Penguin` (can swim, can't fly, can't run, can't sing, can't talk):

```php
class Penguin extends Bird implements SwimmingBird { /* implementation */ }
```

Etc, etc. The whole `@package Ornithology` is taking shape.

Users of these classes should check if the instances are implementing the appropriate interfaces:

```php
if ($birdInstance instanceof FlyingBird && $birdInstance->isFlying()) {
   echo "This bird is flying!";
}
```

To simplify the composing of these classes you may want to create some traits:

E.g.

```php
trait FlyingBirdTrait {

    private $flying = false;

    function isFlying():bool {
       return $this->flying;
    }

    function takeOff() {
       $this->flying = true;
    }

    function land() {
       $this->flying = false;
    }

    function fly($bearing, $altitude, $distance) {
       if (!$this->isFlying()) {
           $this->takeOff();
       }
       // calculate new position;

    }
}
```

Which then classes like `Parrot` could use:

```php
class Parrot extends Bird implements TalkingBird, FlyingBird {
    uses FlyingBirdTrait;
    // rest of the implementation, etc;
}
```

Comment: Good answer and it's consistent with Liskov subst.principle

Comment: @yivi Thank you very much for your answer and sorry my late response.

Comment: Not sure that this is a good overall design? Casting and instance type checks would become pretty common when interacting with bird collections in a generic way, unless you have multiple collections specifically typed. Wouldn't it be just better to solve this with the strategy pattern and composition?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a violation of a SOLID principle. It would be a violation of the Liskov principle if a Bird subclass rejected an inherited method, but that's not what you're doing.

I agree your code isn't elegant though. A cleaner solution would be to have an `isFlyingNow` abstract method defined in the Bird superclass, implemented to return `false` in the Ostrich and other non-flying classes. Then you wouldn't need to check at runtime if the object provides this method or not.

Comment: You advise not a cleaner solution, but extra unnecessary code.

Comment: I propose removing the horrible runtime type check and adding a 1-line hook method to a superclass.

Comment: No need "to do" (inherite) stuff that you don't need or never use.

Comment: I certainly didn't suggest doing that.